# Significado de la abreviatura "plan." en el siglo XVIII

Tags: significado, ortografía, historia, abreviaturas

Curioseando la primera edición de la *Orthographia española*, de 1741, encuentro en la fe de erratas el siguiente texto:

[image: Pag.]

Se puede comprobar que se usa "pag." como abreviatura de página. Sin embargo, en el índice de la obra se lee lo siguiente:

[image: Plan.]

Aquí se usa la abreviatura "plan." con (supongo) el mismo significado. ¿A qué palabra se refiere esta abreviatura? ¿Y por qué se usaba en vez de "pag.", que ya existía y de hecho se usó en la misma obra?

Answer (score 1):

Es evidente que refiere a la palabra **plana**.

Basta, creo yo, ver algunas acepciones del DLE para confirmar:

> **plano, -a**
>   **8.** *f.* Cada una de las dos caras o haces de una hoja de papel.
>
> **9.** *f.* Página escrita, especialmente la impresa de los periódicos y de las revistas. *Apareció la noticia en primera plana.*
>
> **11.** *f.* *Impr.* Conjunto de líneas ya ajustadas de que se compone cada página.

Ende tenemos las expresiones como *a toda plana* (tamaño que ocupa la totalidad de un espacio), *cerrar la plana* (acabar o finalizar algo) y *corregir/enmendar la plana* (avisar a alguien de o corregirle algún fallo).

A pesar de que la abreviatura parezca casi innecesaria, dudo que haya otra palabra excepto (tal vez) *plancha* que en la impresión puede significar algo como *lámina* y relacionado más con la reproducción gráfica.

También, el mismo libro usa la palabra *plana* pero nunca *plancha* (pero sí *lámina*)

> ...muchas veces una misma voz escrita por el mismo sugeto en el mismo libro , y en la misma **plana** se encuentra expuesta , y explicada con diversas letras. (92)

Probablemente se usó porque las dos palabras —sobre todo en una editorial/impresora— las habrían usado con mayor frecuencia que hoy. Sería algo como mezclar *línea* y *renglón* que en este contexto también serían sinónimos, sería al antojo casi. Y como las erratas se imprimían después de la impresión del resto del libro, si fueron hechas por una persona diferente, puede que su terminología preferida fuese distinta.

Comment: Tal y como lo expones tiene mucho sentido, pero entonces ¿por qué hacer una abreviatura cuando solo se omite una letra? ¿Eso no va contra las propias normas de ortografía de la RAE?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - That sounds like a good point.  Is there such a thing as an online browsing dictionary in Spanish, where I could see all the words starting with *plan*?

Comment: @aparente001 the [RAE dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario) can do that. You can click on the button to the left of the search box and select the search mode. Very few people know that, maybe it's a flaw in the interface design.

Comment: Posiblemente vendría de *plancha*, no obstante, *plancha* refiere a reproducciones impresas gráficas y aquí hablamos de cosas de texto. No podría decir porque se decidió abreviar, pero abreviaturas de una letra no eran infrecuentes en el pasado.

Comment: (el equivalente moderno más frecuente en este sentido es *lámina*)

Comment: En todo caso, me parece algo ambiguo, he encontrado obras antiguas que refieren tanto a planchas como planas para las páginas =\

Comment: @guifa ¿y los términos "plana" o "plancha" eran de uso común? Estoy pensando en la gente que luego iba a leer la obra, no en los que la imprimieron, claro.

Comment: @carlosalejo no te podría decir la frecuencia de uso (ya que ambas palabras tienen otros usos) pero sí eran usadas las dos por la gente en aquel momento.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Great tip. // Guifa I propose *planilla* (which I found by using Carlos's tip.  I just don't find it logical that someone would abbreviate a five-letter word with a four-letter word.  I can't remember whether I learned *planilla* as the spread of the left and right pages as I'm looking at an open book.  I might be thinking of a different word. // I wonder if *planilla* might have been used to mean sort of a grid on the page.  Your images are such narrow columns that I suppose there was more than one column on the page.  It looks like your second image...

Comment: is from a listing of corrections, sort of a table of contents.  So maybe the reader is being sent from the quasi-table of contents to an inner part of the book.  There are numbers after *plan.*  It might be helpful to trace the link in a couple of examples, to see if one can understand the pattern.